# Steps for the installation of latex in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, latex

I tried to install the texlive on my Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit laptop) using the following commands in terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gedit-latex-plugin texlive-fonts-recommended latex-beamer texpower texlive-pictures texlive-latex-extra texpower-examples imagemagick
```

After that when I tried to run a tex program, but no output was produced.

Can you lead me to install latex successfully in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: What is the result of the command ***pdflatex***?

Comment: You might take a look at e.g. [Installation of texlive-full on Ubuntu 12.04](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134365/installation-of-texlive-full-on-ubuntu-12-04). There you find suggestsions like `sudo apt-get install texlive`. I am missing the plain texlive package from your command given ...

Comment: @AnjanaPDas:  Please check in terminal `which latex`.